# Task behaviour on fault

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code:

```
Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception();})
  .ContinueWith(t =>
  {
    if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
     {
       OnFaulted();
     }
     if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
     {
       OnCompleted();
     } 
});
```

When I run it, only **OnFaulted()** is called as it should. If I swap the two blocks in the **if** check like this (which is basically the same as the code above, but anyway):

```
Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception();})
      .ContinueWith(t =>
      {
        if (t.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
         {
           OnCompleted();
         }
         else if (t.Status == TaskStatus.Faulted)
         {
           OnFaulted();
         } 
    });
```

still **OnFaulted()** is called, as it should.

But if I write the code like this:

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception();
        })
           .ContinueWith(t =>
           {
               OnCompleted();
           }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
           .ContinueWith(t =>
           {
               OnFaulted();
           }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
           ;
```

neither **OnCompleted** nor **OnFaulted** is called. When I swap the **ContinueWith** blocks like this:

```
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            throw new Exception();
        })               
           .ContinueWith(t =>
           {
               OnFaulted();
           }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
           .ContinueWith(t =>
           {
               OnCompleted();
           }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
           ;
```

both **OnFaulted** and **OnCompleted** are called.
How can this behaviour be explained?
Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: With `ContinueWith`, you hook up to the previous task, not to the first one. Now check your task chain, and you will understand it.

Comment: Why are you using `ContinueWith`? The same code could be rewritten as `try{ await Task.Run(..); OnCompleted()} catch { OnFaulted();}`. Are you targeting .NET 4.0?

Comment: I am not targeting .NET 4.0 so I will write it with await. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have

```
T1.ContinueWith(T2, OnCompleted).ContinueWith(T3, OnFaulted)
```

which you should read as

```
(T1.ContinueWith(T2, OnCompleted)).ContinueWith(T3, OnFaulted)
```

in other words, The T3 part is applied to he output of T2, not that of T1.

You would expect (I did at first) that ContinueWith(..., OnCompleted) would pass its input task on to the next stage but instead it returns a new Canceled Task.

And in this case, the OnCompleted condition is not met so the result of T2 is a Canceled, not a Faulted Task so nothing executes.

Answer (score 0):

`ContinueWith` returns a new continuation task. The second time you call it, it is *this* task that you're adding the second continuation to.

So in your example the first task faults (so is not run to completion) and the second continuation task completes (so is not faulted). This is why you're seeing neither / both methods called.